# Using Ajax to Load Data from Joomla Component

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, joomla4

I have been using Joomla 1.5, using the below code to get data from the controller file and it works well.

**Index.html** :

```
$.ajax({
    url         : 'index.php?option=com_users&task=getData',
    success     : function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I have a function like this in **components/com_users/controller.php** file (joomla 1.5) :

```
public static function getData(){
    echo 22;exit;
}
```

But with joomla 4.3.4, they changed the components' structure and were unsure how to get into work.

This is how the joomla 4.3.4 component looks and added same function in this file:
**components/com_users/src/controller/UserController.php**

I am getting this error
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifiying core files is not recommended when building on the Joomla! framework, as the modifications may be overwritten when an update occurs.

Having said that, in J4! you need to include the name of the controller in the task variable. The 404 error is being generated because Joomla! doesn't know which controller to send the request to and will default to using the DisplayController.

Alter the url you are calling from:

```
index.php?option=com_users&task=getData
```

to:

```
index.php?option=com_users&task=user.getdata
```

and this should resolve the 404

Comment: Great and it works. Thanks a lot.